# Is it possible to do a "reverse regex" pattern match?

Tags: apex, map, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I have the following code:

```
if(PATTERN_A.matcher(someValue).matches()){
    model = MODEL_A;
} else if(PATTERN_B.matcher(someValue).matches()){
    model = MODEL_B;
} else if(PATTERN_C.matcher(someValue).matches()){
    model = MODEL_C;
} else if(PATTERN_D.matcher(someValue).matches()){
    model = MODEL_D;
//  etc... 
} else {
    throw new NoMatchException();
}
```

This is very redundant and ugly.

What I'd like is for code like this:

```
Map<Pattern, String> modelByPatternMap = new Map<Pattern, String>{
    PATTERN_A => MODEL_A,
    PATTERN_B => MODEL_B,
    PATTERN_C => MODEL_C,
    PATTERN_D => MODEL_D,
    etc.
};

Pattern pattern = findPattern(someValue);
model = modelByPatternMap.get(pattern);
```

Is there any better way to create an efficient implementation of findPattern() than brute force, iterating through the map keys, trial and error?

Comment: What are `MODEL_A`, `MODEL_B`, etc? What do the expressions actually look like? It seems like you could just use `Type.forName` here but you haven't given enough context to determine if that is a workable suggestion.

Comment: The type of "model" (which, in the code, you can see is a String) is actually unimportant.  The point is only to reverse the normal working of the relationship between a Pattern and some value being matched against it.... Not so dissimilar to how if I have 10 - x = 8, I can flip things around to determine x = 10 - 8, so x must be 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The for loop would be more efficient (e.g. stops at first match). The only way to avoid a for loop would be to sacrifice performance:

```
Map<Boolean, String> theMap = new Map<Boolean, String>() {
  pattern_a.matcher(someValue).matches() => model_a,
  pattern_b.matcher(someValue).matches() => model_b,
  pattern_c.matcher(someValue).matches() => model_c,
  ...
};
if(theMap.containsKey(true)) {
  model = theMap.get(true);
}
```

The code is "cleaner", but the performance will suffer accordingly. A for-each loop over the keys would be more efficient despite adding a few lines of code.

Comment: That's a clever approach, but I agree, I think a loop would be better.... I was hoping there could be some native "reverse match" code, but I couldn't fathom what the implementation would be and I expect (if it existed) under the hood it would pretty much need to do the same thing.  I'm just going to leave this open for a bit to see if any other interesting answers come up.  :-)